# Change User info in Bio metric Device

Tags: c#, biometrics

I have used below code to disable User info in Barometric Device.It works fine as per my requirement.I would like to know below two points in this scenario.

1. How to change User Image when User is disable ---> I have check "SetUserFace" method but I need an example code.

2.How to set SMS for user when User is disable ---> I have check "SetUserSMS" method but I need an example code.

Source Code :-

```
bool bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.1.142", 4370);   // 4370 is port no of attendance machine

if (bIsConnected == true)
{
    string _Name = "", _Password = "";
    int _Privilefe = 0;
    bool _Enabled = false;

    var t = axCZKEM1.SSR_GetUserInfo(1, "4634", out _Name, out _Password, out _Privilefe, out _Enabled);
    t = axCZKEM1.SSR_SetUserInfo(1, "4634", _Name, _Password, _Privilefe, false);

    axCZKEM1.SetUserFace(); // Need Example Code
    axCZKEM1.SetUserSMS(); // Need Example Code

}
```

Comment: Is it barometric (title) or biometric (tag)? What kind of device do you use?

Comment: sorry BioMetric Device,fingerprint attendance machine

Comment: please help,if anybody knows..

Comment: Are you sure above code disables the user from the biometric device. You meant, when the user gives fingerprint at the device, would it say invalid user or access denined? If not, what do you mean by "disabled"

Comment: sorry for late reply,yes It should to say invalid user or access denied when user gives fingerprint.please help how to do this....

Comment: @KHIT please provide additional information which kind of device is used and dlls?